# Is the 2016 "Dirk Gently's Holistic Detective Agency" TV series a direct adaptation from the books?

Tags: adaptation-comparison, dirk-gently

In [the Wikipedia page for the 2010-12 TV series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirk_Gently_(TV_series)#Adaptation) there is a section in which it's mentioned the TV series is not a direct adaptation from the books:

> The screenplay of the pilot by Howard Overman is not a direct adaptation of the novel, but uses certain characters and situations from the novel to form the basis of a new drama centred around Dirk.

It's also followed by a quote from the TV series' creator, in which he explains why they went that way instead of doing a direct adaptation.

In [the Wikipedia page for the 2016 TV series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirk_Gently%27s_Holistic_Detective_Agency_(TV_series)), however, there isn't any mention of whether this newer series is a direct adaptation from the books or not. **Does the 2016 TV series try to follow the story from the books, or is it also a "with characters from..." kinda thing as was the 2010-12 series?**

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The story is completely different from that of the books.  The [show Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirk_Gently%27s_Holistic_Detective_Agency_(TV_series)) summary is below (emphasis mine):

> The show is based around the eccentric Dirk Gently (Samuel Barnett) who claims to be a "holistic detective", investigating obscure cases based on the inter-connectivity of all things. During the first season he befriends **Todd Brotzman** (Elijah Wood) and **Farah Black** (Jade Eshete) who help him with his cases. Dirk's past is linked with **"Project Blackwing"**, a secret CIA project to evaluate subjects with strange abilities. Dirk is not only followed by agents of Blackwing trying to recapture him but also by **Bart Curlish** (Fiona Dourif), another Blackwing subject who considers herself a "holistic assassin" and believes she is destined to kill Dirk.

While the [book's summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirk_Gently%27s_Holistic_Detective_Agency) begins:

> **Richard MacDuff** attends the Coleridge dinner at his old college St Cedd's, where he witnesses his former tutor, **Professor Urban "Reg" Chronotis***, perform an inexplicable magic trick in which he makes a salt cellar disappear, then reveals it by smashing a centuries-old clay pot that a young girl brought to the dinner. The dinner concludes with a reading of Coleridge's poem "Kubla Khan", including a mysterious (and fictional) second part.
>
> Meanwhile, an **Electric Monk** and his horse find a mysterious door on an alien planet, which leads them to Earth. MacDuff and Prof. Chronotis find the horse in the Professor's bathroom, but this does not seem to overly surprise him. The Monk, misunderstanding a casual comment, shoots and kills MacDuff's boss Gordon Way. Way's ghost makes several attempts to contact the living.

I've read/watched both and they are definitely different stories, as can be seen simply by the characters involved (highlighted). Everything from the show is original to the series, except Dirk and the basic idea of his "agency".

@CrowTRobot mentioned that the first episode had a [quote](http://dirkgently.wikia.com/wiki/Horizons#Quotes) referencing a sofa and Thor, implying that the show follows the two completed novels.

> "Have you ever actually solved a case?"
>
> "Sure. Tons. Well, some. Well, a few. There was a bit about a sofa, a thing with Thor..."

Comment: Despite the age disparity of Dirk and different origin story, the TV show also makes it clear that it's a sequel to the books, in the pilot Dirk offhandedly mentions that "There was a bit about a sofa, a thing with Thor": the stuck sofa is a plot point in the first book and Thor is a pivotal character in the second book.

Comment: @CrowTRobot that deserved to be an answer I think (that the series looks like or is a sequel to the books, not an adaptation.)

Comment: Part of the reason they didn't adapt the book was that the book is essentially a recycling of the plot for Shada, the "Lost" Doctor Who Episode from the Tom Baker years, never completed due to a strike.  At the time, there was essentially no way that story was going to see the light of day, so he cannibalized it for the Dirk Gently book. Since then, we've seen the story via a number of adaptations and media, rather requiring they come up with a new story.

Comment: @VBartilucci - Was Douglas Adams writing for Dr. Who back then? Or did he hear/know about the "lost" episode, and run with the premise?

Comment: Yes, Adams was a writer and script editor for Doctor Who back then. He wrote "Shada", "The Pirate Planet", and "City of Death" (under a pseudonym). "City of Death" is probably closer to the plot of the first Dirk Gently novel than "Shada", and certainly closer than any of the TV versions of Dirk Gently.

Comment: *implying that the show follows the two completed novels* – I wouldn’t consider these more than allusions to the book. There are a lot of things that make a common past rather unlikely, e.g., TV Dirk’s past with Blackwing and resulting general cluenessness about real life does not match with Book Dirk’s years of history of interacting with our world and being much more experienced with life (CC @CrowTRobot).

Comment: Also, the 2016 series is heavily Americanized.  Not sure why a BBC series would add so much US-oriented content though, maybe they anticipated selling it over here.

Comment: The Wikipedia page says it's produced by BBC _America_, @RBarryYoung. It's also co-produced by Netflix, which is an American company too.

Comment: For what it's worth at this late date, the first Dirk Gently is far from a "recycling" of the plot to Shada. One charater-- Professor Chronotis-- appears in both, but the plots and other characters are completely different.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the Wikipedia pages, and having read the books, it appears to me that the 2016 series deviates even more from the books than the 2010-2012 series.  I don't see any shared plot points, except perhaps that all use time machines.